# How to write a mocked unit test for a db insert method in Springboot REST API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-data

I have a REST API written in Spring Boot.

Now I want to create unit tests with JUnit and Mockito that mock the database operations.

Here is the endpoint that inserts a new customer to the db.

```
@RestController
public class CustomerController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    
    
    @PostMapping(value="/customers", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> addCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
        
        Customer newCustomer = customerRepository.save(customer);       
        
        return new ResponseEntity<Customer>(newCustomer, HttpStatus.OK) ;
    }
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testAddCustomer() {
        
    Customer customer = Mockito.mock(Customer.class);
    customer.setIdCustomer(1L);     
    customer.setName("Pete");
    customer.setAge(35);
    customer.setEmail("pete@test.com");
                
    when(customerRepository.save(customer)).thenReturn((Customer) Stream.of(customer));
        
    CustomerController customerController = new CustomerController();       

    ResponseEntity<Customer> respCustomer = customerController.addCustomer(customer);
        
    assertTrue(respCustomer.getBody().getIdCustomer() != null);
        
}
```

I'm getting a null pointer exception on the following line:

```
 when(customerRepository.save(customer)).thenReturn((Customer) Stream.of(customer));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

@Mock
private CustomerRepository customerRepository

in your test and configure the repository using mockito API

Comment: what is the code for the @Test method? That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: I updated the question adding what I have up to now.

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this

```
    @Test
    public void testFindTheGreatestFromAllData() {
        DataService dataServiceMock = mock(DataService.class);
        when(dataServiceMock.retrieveAllData()).thenReturn(new int[] { 24, 15, 3 });
        SomeBusinessImpl businessImpl = new SomeBusinessImpl(dataServiceMock);
        int result = businessImpl.findTheGreatestFromAllData();
        assertEquals(24, result);
    }
```

Comment: I updated the question adding what I have up to now that is not working.

Comment: check if customRepository is not null when you run your test. use breakpoints and debug mode

Comment: Yes, it is null. How to fix it? It is autowired at the class level. ```public class CustomerControllerTest { @Autowired private CustomerRepository customerRepository;...```

Comment: Now I noticed I was mocking the wrong class. The repository class is the one that needs to be mocked. So I did the following changes: 1) commented out the @Autowired line; 2) Changed the first line of the testAddCustomer method to Customer customer = new Customer(); 3) Added the following line: CustomerRepository customerRepository = Mockito.mock(CustomerRepository.class); Getting a type conversion error now: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head cannot be cast to class restapicustomers.model.Customer